# Drag and drop panel controls are overlapping due to incorrect indexes

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm experimenting with a form that contains some vertically stacked panels and I'm trying to implement some drag and drop so they can be re-ordered. It's working well so far apart from one bug that I can't figure out.
The premise is that it's a list of files which must be kept vertically stacked, but can be re-ordered as the user sees fit, to form a list of pages for a document I'll produce later.

Try the following code and you should get a form with 6 stacked panels. Click and drag any one of them up or down and they will re-order.

**The problem** is that if you drag one up and down ***really fast*** they start to overlap with each other.
I've put the shortcut CTRL + B in there to list the current panel top positions at any given time and you'll see that you get duplicate numbers when you shouldn't.

The problem is with the MouseMove event. I'm sure it's something like a race condition where the dictionary can't keep up or the indexes don't calculate fast enough but I'm scratching my head. I've tried locking them but it hasn't helped.
I'm sure there's a better way to implement this so I'm open to suggestions, but given that this will never have more than say 30 panels this suits my needs.

Apologies for the messy-ness, I was planning to tidy up later!

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.SuspendLayout();
    this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
    this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
    this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 601);
    this.DoubleBuffered = true;
    this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    this.MaximizeBox = false;
    this.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 640);
    this.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 640);
    this.Name = "Form1";
    this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
    this.Text = "Form1";
    this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
    this.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.Form1_KeyDown);
    this.ResumeLayout(false);
}

Dictionary<int, Panel> panelPositions = new Dictionary<int, Panel>();
static Random rnd = new Random();
int y;
int start;
static int index, previndex, currentindex, newindex, maxindex;
bool isDragging;
Panel currentPanel;
static readonly object Lock = new Object();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Width = 300;
    Height = 640;
    int count = 5;
    int currentTop = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++)
    {
        Panel panel = new Panel();
        panel.Width = 300;
        panel.Height = 100;
        panel.Top = currentTop;
        panel.BackColor = RandomColor();
        panel.Margin = Padding.Empty;
        panel.Padding = Padding.Empty;
        panel.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;

        Label label = new Label();
        label.Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 24.0f);
        label.Text = (i + 1).ToString();
        label.Top = 20;
        label.Left = 20;
        label.AutoSize = true;

        panel.Controls.Add(label);
        panel.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(MouseisDown);
        panel.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(MouseMoves);
        panel.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(MouseisUp);

        lock (Lock)
        {
            panelPositions.Add(i, panel);
        }

        Controls.Add(panel);

        currentTop += 100;
    }

    lock (Lock)
    {
        maxindex = panelPositions.Count - 1;
    }
}

private void MouseisUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (isDragging)
    {
        if (newindex < maxindex)
        {
            currentPanel.Top = newindex * 100;
        }
        else
        {
            currentPanel.Top = maxindex * 100;
        }
    }

    isDragging = false;
}

// I'M SURE THE PROBLEM IS IN HERE SOMEWHERE.
private void MouseMoves(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // CHECK THE MOUSE IS STILL DOWN
    if (isDragging)
    {
        // DRAG PANEL VERTICALLY WITH MOUSE
        currentPanel.Location = new Point(currentPanel.Left, e.Y + currentPanel.Top - y);

        // WORK OUT NEW INDEX POSITION
        newindex = 0;
        if ((currentPanel.Top + e.Y) > 0)
        {
            newindex = ((currentPanel.Top + e.Y) / 100);
        }

        // NEW POSITION?
        if (currentindex != newindex)
        {
            // TRACK CHANGES
            previndex = currentindex;
            currentindex = newindex;

            /* PRETTY SURE IT'S THIS BIT THAT'S WRONG */
            // CHECK WE'RE NOT OUT OF BOUNDS
            if (currentindex <= maxindex)
            {
                lock (Lock)
                {
                    // RE-ARRANGE PANEL INDEX
                    panelPositions[previndex] = panelPositions[currentindex];
                    panelPositions[currentindex] = currentPanel;
                    panelPositions[previndex].Top = previndex * 100;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private void MouseisDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        currentPanel = sender as Panel;
        isDragging = true;
        currentPanel.BringToFront();
        y = e.Y;
        start = currentPanel.Top;

        int i = 0;
        if (currentPanel.Top > 0)
        {
            i = currentPanel.Top;
            i = (i / 100);
        }
        index = i;

        previndex = i;
        currentindex = i;
    }
    else
    {
        isDragging = false;
    }
}

private Color RandomColor()
{
    Color randColor;

    randColor = Color.FromArgb(RandomRGB(), RandomRGB(), RandomRGB());

    return randColor;
}
private int RandomRGB()
{
    return rnd.Next(1, 256);
}

private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.B)
    {
        string message = string.Empty;
        int count = panelPositions.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            message += @"Panel " + i.ToString() + @": " + panelPositions[i].Top.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
        }
        MessageBox.Show(message);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

**Edit:** I think it's something to do with when the panel goes outside the bottom bounds of the form. If you drag within the form the issue doesn't occur. I think it's to do with the previous index, but I can't see it.

Comment: Another try. Reset the currentIndex if it is not inside the bound to the prevIndex before leaving.

Comment: I think that did it. If you post it as an answer I'll accept.

Comment: Sorry out for work now, no time to write a full explained answer if you wish feel free to accept the other solution....

Comment: There's no need for a massive answer, I understood what you meant and fixed it with one line of code ;-) Thanks for your help. As you have 117k rep I'll accept the other answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
    // NEW POSITION?
    if (currentindex != newindex)
```

To

```
    // NEW POSITION?
    if (currentindex != newindex && newindex <= maxindex)
```

I think you know why :)

P.s: Your "Edit" section is a bit misleading.